# Create own commands for mathematical article. (E.g. Theorem, Proof, Colloral etc.)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, theorems

si I'd like to have something like:

**Theorem 1.1**

-----This is some nice Theorem

-----Very nice indeed

Whereas ----- are white spaces. I'll have several such "blocks", like e.g. "Theorem"; "Corrollar", "Prove", "Lemma" etc.

I'm wondering how I can do that in a good practice way.

Comment: Please have a look at the [description of tag `theorems`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/theorems/info). BTW: You should always show us a [minimal but working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you already have tried.

Comment: Indentation is handled by \leftskip and \rightskip, and occasionally \hangindent.  It doesn't work with lists, however, as they recompute \leftskip using their own system.